# Count occurrences of a special word in a string in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL, I want to find the number of occurrence of particular word in a string.

For example I want to count the number of occurrence the word `NodeId` in the following string:

```
[{"NodeId":4,"NodeCondition":"1 > 2 AND 1=1"},{"NodeId":5,"NodeCondition":"56 %2 = 0"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a JSON string. The most accurate way of doing this is to shred the JSON and count how many `NodeId` keys you have.

```sql
DECLARE @String nvarchar(max) = '[{"NodeId":4,"NodeCondition":"1 > 2 AND 1=1"},{"NodeId":5,"NodeCondition":"56 %2 = 0"}]';

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM OPENJSON(@String)
  WITH (NodeId int)
WHERE NodeId IS NOT NULL;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=64ca2ed3855b1fe5ccf7fc91c1b2ff9b)

Note that just counting how many times you have `NodeId` in the string is not good enough, as it may be in one of the values, not in a key, or it may be in a key but not the whole key name.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the word `NodeId` from the string and then compare it with the outcome string.

Try this code:

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"NodeId":4,"NodeCondition":"1 > 2 AND 1=1"},{"NodeId":5,"NodeCondition":"56 %2 = 0"}]';
DECLARE @stringLEN INT = LEN(@string);
DECLARE @tmpString INT = (SELECT LEN(REPLACE(@string, 'NodeId', '')));

SELECT (@stringLEN - @tmpString) / LEN('NodeId');
```